# INSTEAD OF vs AFTER (SQL) How many times on a table can they be used?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

To my understating, INSTEAD OF trigger can only be used on a table only once. On the other hand, AFTER can be used multiple times on a table. Are these statements true?

Answer (score 1):

Correct.  Trying to add a second INSTEAD OF trigger fails with

```
Msg 2111, Level 16, State 1, Procedure xxxx, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 4]
Cannot create trigger 'xxxx' on table 'tablename' because an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger already exists on this object.
```

Multiple AFTER triggers are allowed and will all fire.

It's all documented here: [CREATE TRIGGER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> At most, you can define one `INSTEAD OF` trigger per `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statement on a table or view.

Comment: You could have tried this a lot quicker than the time it took to write this question.